# Blocking the scroll-bar's value change event-handler until the bar is released

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar

Suppose, I need to perform a resource intensive task with the movement of scroll-bar.

```
private void hScrollBar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReCalculate();
}

void ReCalculate()
{
    try
    {
        int n = hScrollBar1.Value;
        int f0 = hScrollBar2.Value;
        int theta = hScrollBar3.Value;
        int a = hScrollBar4.Value;

        //... resource-intensive task which uses scroll-bar's values.
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, the event-handler gets executed with the slightest change of the scroll-bar.

I need to block the execution of event-handler until the mouse is released.

So, I tried using mouse-enter and mouse-leave event-handlers like:

```
bool ready = false;
private void hScrollBars_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ready = false;
}

private void hScrollBars_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ready = true;
}
```

along with a checking like:

```
void ReCalculate()
{
    if(ready)
    {
        try
        {
            int n = hScrollBar1.Value;
            int f0 = hScrollBar2.Value;
            int theta = hScrollBar3.Value;
            int a = hScrollBar4.Value;

            //... resource-intensive task which uses scroll-bar's values.
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: What if the user uses the wheel?

Comment: @LarsTech, yes. you raised a valid point. Wheels are also giving same problem.

Comment: Or when user uses arrow keys? Or when press the left/right scroll button and keep it pressed a few seconds and then release?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, Yes. Those cases should also be taken into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle [`Scroll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll?view=netframework-4.7.2) event and check the [`e.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.type?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ScrollEventArgs_Type) and if it was `ScrollEventType.EndScroll`, run your logic:

```
private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
    {
        // Scroll has ended
        // You can use hScrollBar1.Value
    }
}
```